# math.group error from regex tuples in python

Tags: python, regex, list, tuples

I want to be able to manipulate the results of this regex and match it into groups so I can manipulate it. I get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
```

My code is as follows:

```
sampleText= 'LOC OL85M132 LOC OL3M051'
matchLOC=re.findall(r'(LOC)\s([^\W\d_]{2})(\d+)M(\d{3})',sampleText)
for i in matchLOC:
     print(i)
```

My result with this is:

```
('LOC', 'OL', '85', '132')
('LOC', 'OL', '3', '051')
```

This is fine but when I try and assign the groups to variables like:

```
MP=matchLoc.group(2)
Yards=matchLoc.group(3)
```

I get that error above.
I want to:

1) Assign the third group to a variable 'MP'

2) Assign the fourth group to variable 'Yards'

From here on I would then like to do a series of manipulations. eg add the digit 0 to the end of the last number and also if-else loops such as

```
if Yards >= 130:
   print('Yards = ' + str(int(Yards)-100))
   print('MP = ' + str(int(MP) + 0.5))
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re
sampleText= 'LOC OL85M132 LOC OL3M051'
for m in re.finditer(r'(LOC)\s([^\W\d_]{2})(\d+)M(\d{3})',sampleText):
    #print (m.group(3) + " : " + m.group(4))
    MP = int(m.group(3))
    Yards = int(m.group(4))
    if Yards >= 130:
        print('Yards = ' + str(Yards-100))
        print('MP = ' + str(MP + 0.5))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/1yuGBj)

I have not modified your regex, but I see no point in capturing `(LOC)` since it is known text. Note that modifying the capturing groups, you will shift the group ids and you will need to revise the whole code. That's why I kept it as in the original code.

Comment: Your solution only does it for one of them not both? I needed an output similar to eg LOC OL85M132   MP=X Yards=Y                                         and then next line LOC OL3M051 MP=X Yards=Y. Thanks for the help by the way. Appreciate it (y)

Comment: In the second match, `Yards` < 130. Uncomment the commented line to see that the regex is working correctly.

Comment: Yeah man thanks. Ill test it out, but for the time being this seems good.

Answer (score 0):

re.finall():

> Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

you probably want :

```
for _, _, mp, yards in matchLOC:
    yards = int(yards)
    if yards >= 130:
       ...
```

Comment: But then I just get this AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: apologies - I mis-remembered the return format for `findall()` - does the updated answer do what you need?

Comment: Sorry could you just explain that. I'm just beginning out with python.